# How can I get my Ryu combos to end in Ultra/Super instead of a Shoryuken?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv

I've been playing Street Fighter since SF2 but I was used to only mashing buttons randomly and trying to finish the playthrough and see the ending thanks to limitless continues or easy modes. Recently I've decided to play like a real man. I've started SSFIV AE from the easiest difficulty and whenever I finish the playthrough without continues, I've increased the difficulty (I don't know is it the right way to improve myself but seems working for now). Lastly, I've finished very hard difficulty and now I'm trying to finish the hardest.

My problem is, whenever I start a combo and try to finish it with a super/ultra combo, I end up with a Shoryuken and lose all my momentum, even getting easily punished(I've lost lots of matches just because of this). Whatever I do, I can't get over with this problem. I'm playing with a regular Xbox controller-like gamepad and my character is Ryu.

Is there anyone that could help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting a Shoryuken when you're attempting to do a Super/Ultra input, you're probably hitting the final button input(s) too early, or aren't fully completing the directional inputs properly. This is a common issue, and to understand why it happens, think about Ryu's Super input command for a moment:

D, D/F, F, D, D/F, F + P

Then, pretend you were to input the P a little too early:

D, D/F, **F, D, D/F + P**

The bolded part is, exactly, the input for a Shoryuken, which is usually why you'll get accidental Shoryukens when attempting a Super, or an EX Shoryuken when attempting an Ultra. Try being more deliberate about completing the input, only pressing the Punch inputs once you've fully completed the motion. Training Mode is a great way to practice your execution.

If you continue to have problems, another (somewhat less orthodox) way to avoid the issue is to mentally add an U/F input at the end of the command, and trying to hit Punch when you get to U/F. If you consistently hit the button early, it may let you trick yourself to hitting the Punch input at the right time (during Forward). It might also just reinforce bad habits, though, so be careful.

Comment: I've already tried the first way you suggest but I guess the second way would work for me. Thank you for the answer!